# Creating blob storage service programmatically in Azure

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

currently I'm playing around with Azure and thinking about a multi-tanent web app where users can create an instance of the app, where more users can register to upload and share files within this instance. I've created a blob storage service and created several containers. However, I'm not sure how customers may think about the fact, that they share their blob service with other users and files are only separated by containers. I would like that each user gets instead his own blob service. However the web app should be shared still by a single web worker role.

This sounds easy for every instance you create by hand, however I want the blob service to be created automatically as the user registers and creates his instance of the web app. Unfortunately I haven't found yet any information about how I could accomplish this. I've found only the blob storage api to query the service, not for creating it.

Can anybody lead me in the right direction? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a storage account programmatically (see "Create Storage Account": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264518.aspx), but I wouldn't recommend creating a different account for each user. The limit on how many storage accounts can be created per subscription is fairly low. (I believe the default is five and you can call to get your quota increased to twenty.)

In general, the recommendation is to go ahead and use the same storage account for all your customers. I believe your concern is about data security, but adding multiple storage accounts doesn't really change the security dynamic. (The trust boundary is still between you and the end user, since only your code will directly access storage.)

Comment: Never thought about a limited number of subscriptions peer account. Thank you many times!